# Rich text not preserving original format [Laravel]

Tags: php, css, laravel, styles, richtext

I've been breaking my head for a while with this problem. I have a web app that saves clinical exams so they can be deliver and printed to clients and other branch offices

So far so good, for other than the rich text won't preserve the style when show back

it will just randomly insert -tabs- or -spaces-, for no good reason, or no reason I'm aware of

While capturing text:

[image: while capturing text]

[image: Now printing the text (space and tabs scrambled):]

[image: Inspecting the element, I'm using pre-warp]

Im using pre-warp in my style sheet, text area for posting, and table->text in my Laravel model-migration

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if it could be helpful, but maybe you can solve it with a CSS for printing: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Comment: Thanks! we may be able to work something out with that